# why unity doesn't recognize "||"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a clock, and unity recognizes "||" as an error

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad1)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
    continuous = true;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
    continuous = false;
}
```

This is what Unity says:

[image]

Normally, any IDE/engine recognizes "||" as an "or", i dont know what to do...

Comment: Your brackets are unbalanced.

Comment: Remove the close parens immediately before and the open parens immediately after. Also... Don't paste [links to] images of errors; paste the error text into the question. Text in images isn't searchable and most people don't want to click a link

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are a little bit off. Your `||` operator was outside the `if` statement.

Also, this isn't a Unity error. This is a C# error.

```
if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad1) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1) ) 
{
    continuous = true;
}

if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2) ) 
{
    continuous = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad1)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
    continuous = true;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
    continuous = false;
}
```

to this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad1) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
    continuous = true;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
    continuous = false;
}
```